# create sub vocabulary term for taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I want to create sub child for vocabulary list item which is created in taxonomy.I have the vocabulary 'Service Line' which has the list item 1.cloud 2.retail.I want to create the sub child for the list 'cloud1,cloud2,cloud3' for the list item 'cloud' and 'retail1,retail2,retail3' for the list item 'retail' in drupal 7.
How to create the sub child the each list item.

Answer (score 1):

When you add term you have an option to specify parent/root element.
Is it what you are looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also drag-n-drop the terms on the taxonomy page.
[image]